# MySQL server has gone away wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I worked in wordpress plugin wp security and i did backup some files when wordpress blocked and next thing that is poping out is this i dont know how to fix this..

```
Settings (general_settings) Error: fetch - MySQL server has gone away
---
Query: select * from d4o1yq7rl_revslider_settings
#0 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php(22): UniteFunctionsRev::throwError('fetch - MySQ...', -1)
#1 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php(36): UniteDBRev->throwError('fetch - MySQ...')
#2 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/db.class.php(124): UniteDBRev->checkForErrors('fetch')
#3 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/revslider_params.class.php(42): UniteDBRev->fetch('d4o1yq7rl_revsl...')
#4 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/revslider_operations.class.php(331): RevSliderParams->getFieldFromDB('general')
#5 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/settings/general_settings.php(26): RevOperations->getGeneralSettingsValues()
#6 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/base_admin.class.php(220): require('/home/hkt/publi...')
#7 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider_admin.php(49): UniteBaseAdminClassRev::requireSettings('general_setting...')
#8 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider_admin.php(32): RevSliderAdmin->init()
#9 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php(77): RevSliderAdmin->__construct('/home/hkt/publi...')
#10 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-settings.php(203): include_once('/home/hkt/publi...')
#11 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-config.php(98): require_once('/home/hkt/publi...')
#12 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-load.php(29): require_once('/home/hkt/publi...')
#13 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(30): require_once('/home/hkt/publi...')
#14 /home/hkt/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/hkt/publi...')
#15 {main}
Revolution Slider Error:Settings general not found
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/inc_php/framework/base_admin.class.php:222) in /home/hkt/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 899
```

please if someone can help that would be great i must have this site uploaded in 2 hours!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693796/wordpress-database-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away-for-query?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801794/mysql-server-has-gone-away?rq=1

Comment: The urgency doesn't help much here, in terms of getting help, although it will help get you downvotes. Have you tried deleting /home/hkt/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/ ? It's standard WP procedure to remove plugins that are causing issues, and that looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably due to closed mysql connection or timeout from the query. You can find the details here
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html
If its a local mysql server which can be managed by you, try restarting it
else use another mysql user to connect

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the max_allowed_packet setting to a larger value in the server.

Open "`my.ini/cnf`", located in your MySQL installation folder, and under [mysqld] section change "`max_allowed_packet = 64M`" and don't forget to restart the server. 
You can check the value by executing:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```