# Ubuntu 20.04 - Stopped MySQL. Now it won't start (error 13, permission denied)

Tags: mysql, permissions, ubuntu-20.04

Running a DigitalOcean LAMP Stack (1GB VPS) on Ubuntu 20.04, I was getting intermittent "Error establshing a database connection" errors in Wordpress when uploading media files. This was throwing the following Apache error:

`WordPress database error MySQL server has gone away for query...`

While this issue was occurring, MySQL logs repeatedly printed the following and nothing else since:

```
    2020-12-19T12:14:43.708558Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
    2020-12-19T12:14:43.992793Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu).
    2020-12-19T12:14:59.498001Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) starting as process 190645
    2020-12-19T12:14:59.512933Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
    2020-12-19T12:15:00.093514Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
    2020-12-19T12:15:00.448326Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '127.0.0.1' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
    2020-12-19T12:15:00.524531Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2020-12-19T12:15:00.543848Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
    2020-12-19T12:15:00.652394Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
```

I tried this fix: [WordPress database error MySQL server has gone away for query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693796/wordpress-database-error-mysql-server-has-gone-away-for-query)

Still the website was displaying the error, so I thought I should restart MySQL, but it won't restart.

With `sudo service MySQL start`, I get

`Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Running the first command:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-12-19 12:45:50 UTC; 1min 3s ago
Process: 192068 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 192076 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 192076 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Status: "Server startup in progress"
  Error: 13 (Permission denied)
```

Running the second command

```
 Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
  Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages.
  Pass -q to turn off this notice.
 -- Defined-By: systems
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 --
 -- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
 --
 -- The job identifier is 8.
 Dec 19 12:13:48 server systemd[189372]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
 -- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
 -- Defined-By: systems
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 --
 -- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
 --
 -- The job identifier is 11.
 Dec 19 12:13:48 server systemd[189372]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
 -- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
 -- Defined-By: systems
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 --
 -- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
 --
 -- The job identifier is 9.
 Dec 19 12:13:48 server systemd[189372]: Reached target Sockets.
 -- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
 -- Defined-By: systems
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 --
 -- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
 --
 -- The job identifier is 5.
 Dec 19 12:13:48 server systemd[189372]: Reached target Basic System.
 -- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
 -- Defined-By: systems
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 --
 -- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
 --
 -- The job identifier is 2.
 Dec 19 12:13:48 server systemd[189372]: Reached target Main User Target.
 -- Subject: A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully
 -- Defined-By: systems
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 --
 -- A start job for unit UNIT has finished successfully.
 --
 -- The job identifier is 1.
 Dec 19 12:13:48 server systemd[189372]: Startup finished in 168ms.
 -- Subject: User manager start-up is now complete
 -- Defined-By: systems
 -- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
 --
 -- The user manager instance for user 1000 has been started. All services queued
 -- for starting have been started. Note that other services might still be starting
 -- up or be started at any later time.
 --
 -- Startup of the manager took 168965 microseconds.
 Dec 19 12:15:07 server sudo[190726]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
 Dec 19 12:15:09 server sudo[190726]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
 Dec 19 12:30:17 server sudo[191518]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
 Dec 19 12:30:19 server sudo[191518]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
 Dec 19 12:32:25 server sudo[191686]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
 Dec 19 12:32:27 server sudo[191686]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
```

The first error led me to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228827/mysql-error-13-permission-denied

However MySQL already owns /var/lib/mysql. The owner of /usr/sbin/mysqld is root. This is the same as on another server where MySQL works fine. Should I really change this?

Comment: Because of `Status: "Server startup in progress"` you are getting an `Error: 13 (Permission denied)`.  You should find out why the starting is `in progress`.

Comment: @Luuk I tried looking around for this error. There was a suggestion it was to do with disk space but I have 20 GB remaining. netstat shows MySQL not running. There is nothing further (since I stopped it) appearing in MySQL error logs. Should I try to do a hard kill maybe? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36102/how-to-properly-kill-mysql

Answer (score 9):

The issue was that I had given my user ownership of `/var/log/mysql` to read the files. `sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /var/log/mysql` allowed me to start **mysql**.

Comment: Man this answer is the only fish in a sea of noise; Thanks alot ma man

Answer (score 3):

It might happen if you manually delete `binlog` files.

- Check `/var/log/mysql/error.log` to see the bottom lines, if the reason is related to `binlog` files.
- if **yes**, then clearing the content of file `/var/lib/mysql/binlog.index` and then restarting mysql helped me.

Comment: Thanks a LOT... now I have to revise my opinion about magic! Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Simple run update command
**apt-get update

apt-get upgrade**
It auto update permissions necessary for mysql.
It solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into same problem. I moved mysql data directory from `/var/lib/mysql` to `/media/anand/databank/mysql`. I gave all read write permissions to all users/groups but mysql server failed to restart with `Error: 13 (Permission denied)`. After repeatedly reading out this and other thread,   I could figure out that for folder `anand` no access permissions was given to others (that includes user mysql). Hence, even if a user (mysql in my case) have full access to `mysql` folder but that user will not reach `mysql` folder till that user gets permission to access `anand` folder. Once, I granted read only permission to mysql user on foledr `anand`, mysql server started without error.

**In nutshell, if you grant permission to a user on some folder. Please check, that such user has at least read-only/access-files permissions on all parent folders**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue
`system status mysql Main PID: 178577 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Status: "Server startup in progress" Error: 13 (Permission denied)` 
solution for me
`chown mysql:mysql -R /var/lib/mysql/ /var/log/mysql/` 
Start up ok

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in MySQL 8 under Ubuntu: even if you don't have apparmor installed that limits the path use, and the permissions are correctly set, MySQL fails due to permission errors when using non-standard data directory (other than `/var/lib/mysql`), and you will see the lines such as those in the log file:

```
2024-03-21T15:12:07.753574Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /data/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2024-03-21T15:12:07.753653Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 1550168
2024-03-21T15:12:07.755488Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file /data/mysql/mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
2024-03-21T15:12:07.755499Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /data/mysql/ is case insensitive
mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
2024-03-21T15:12:07.756320Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-03-21T15:12:07.756425Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.36-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

If you use other location for data than the default `/var/lib/mysql`, move data back to that location and update `datadir` in the config file (see below for a sample config that works), and it will run normally, even no permission change or reinstall is needed—it will start normally.

```
[client]
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
secure_file_priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
log_error=/var/log/mysql/error.log
```