# MySQL Cannot start in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql

I installed LAMP in my newly installed ubuntu 22.04 a few days before and everything was working perfectly. But today when I tried to start mysql It is showing the following error.

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-05-01 09:35:16 IST; 19s ago
Process: 6471 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 6479 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)


Main PID: 6479 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 2 (No such file or directory)
        CPU: 312ms

May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

journalctl shows the following:

```
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3436 and the job result is done.
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
May 01 09:35:16 g-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 3436 and the job result is failed.
```

Comment: Check that `/usr/sbin/mysqld` exists and that it is executable.

Comment: @StephenC yes it exists. It shows some error when i run `/usr/sbin/mysqld`

Comment: http://ix.io/3WHQ @StephenC

Comment: `"2022-05-01T04:27:10.155825Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (OS errno: 13 - Permission denied)"` - There's your problem!

Comment: OK ... might be a different problem.  Check the logfiles for mysql to see if you are getting a similar problem when you are starting it via systemd.

Comment: I tried `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
` but nothing happens.

Comment: @StephenC There was no error files in `/var/log`. I created a directory `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. the file is empty. `sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld` returns http://ix.io/3WI0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally after hours of trying to figure out problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65370142/ubuntu-20-04-stopped-mysql-now-it-wont-start-error-13-permission-denied) thread solved the issue.
I just run the command `sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /var/log/mysql` . That solved the issue.

If you don't have that directory, you can create it and set permissions to write in

`$ sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mysql/` 
`$ sudo chown mysql:mysql -R /var/log/mysql`

Comment: WTF. It wasn't enough for me, but it prevented the start from failing...

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening it's likely theres been error during the installation of mysql. If the above don't work try these:

Purge mysql:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-* 
mysql-client-core-*
```

Make sure all mysql files are removed:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
```

Reboot your system and try using

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

to make sure your packages aren corrupted or broken and use the

sudo apt install mysql-server --fix-broken

Was running into these issues and this enabled me to install successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After an update of the mysql server the #inndb_redo folder didn't get restored for some reason.
So as root:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql
mkdir "#innodb_redo"
chown mysql:mysql #innodb_redo
systemctl restart mysql
```